# Does the package authblk prevent the appearance of the name of the author?

Tags: packages, elsarticle, front-matter

I'm now writing an article to submit to a journal published by the Elsevier.

And there was a problem with the name of the author not appearing.

I tried to find the origin of the problem and when I removed \usepackage{authblk},

the name appeared.

So I want to know if there is a cause and effect relationship!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authblk` shouldn't be used inside `elsarticle` class. It redefines `\@author` in a way incompatible with `elsarticle`. As you can see, the following simple MWE won't compile:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{authblk}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

As one can see from the documentation of `elsarticle`, it has its own system for the author block:
[image]

Thus there's no need to use external packages.